# How to objectify multiple "target" in visual basic?

Tags: syntax, vb6

I have a class object "A" that I want to objectify/represent using `target`. I can accomplish this by the following code (visual basic):

```
dim target : target = A
```

Now, if the object A has a property, for example, `a0`, I can access this property by

```
target.a0
```

However, if now I have another class object B, and its property is `b0` instead of `a0`, I have to manually access this property by changing the target first and then access its property as following:

```
dim target : target = B
target.b0
```

What I want to accomplish is to objectify the `a0` and `b0` using another `target`-like representation. If possible, this is similar to what I am going after:

```
dim target1 : target1 = A
dim target2 : target2 = a0
target1.target2
```

I know this doesn't work, because VB didn't really think `target1` is a keyword like `target`. Could anyone provide a good solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What VB? If not VB6 please tag properly e.g. VB.NET or VBA or VBScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding of what you're trying to accomplish (which may be a bold assumption on my part), you can't do what you're trying to do. Assuming this is all VB.NET, the declaration of "Dim target2" is completely dissimilar from the *reference* to a property or method reference as you offer in "target1.target2". In the latter instance, ".target2" has to be a property or method of the type of which target1 was declared. The direct declaration I think you're trying to accomplish just isn't the way the language is constructed.

You could probably pull off some syntax tricks to *approach* what this does, but in terms of making "target1.target2" resolve to a literal reference to "A.a0" in a declarative manner such as that just won't work.

If I've misunderstood, I'll offer apologies in advance.

Good luck!

Comment: But knowing what I wanted to accomplish, do you have an idea of how that could be done?